# Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 62926848 bytes)

Tags: php, wampserver, laravel-5.5

I am facing problem Memory size exhausted  in laravel 5.5. 
Its before  means 5.4 version my code is working but not now.
For this i increased memory size from php.ini file memory_limit 1024M. but not working. 
basically i am converting Base64 file format file  and then storing into my local storage of pc or server.

**Controller Code**

```
    public static  function convertBase64ToFile ( $file   , $dir  )
{
    $pos  = strpos($file, ';');
    $type = explode(':', substr($file, 0, $pos))[1];
    $format = explode('/',$type);

    $exploded = explode(',', $file);

    $decoded = base64_decode($exploded[1]);

    if(str_contains($exploded[0], $format[1]))

    { $extension = $format[1];}

    $filename = str_random().'.'.$extension;

    $path = public_path().$dir.$filename;

    file_put_contents($path, $decoded);

    return $filename;
   }
```

message:

> "Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65015808 bytes)", "exception": "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException",

Comment: How big's the file?

Comment: check the math. I see 134 MB, not 1024.

Comment: Take a look at phpinfo output and do a check if the memory_limit has been changed.

Comment: You should be able to accomplish something like this without having to load the entire file into memory. If you can better describe the data in `$file` and where it comes from I should be able to suggest a better plan of attack.

Answer (score 0):

In wamp you got 2 `php.ini` files. One is in `\wamp\bin\php\php.x.y.z` but this one is only for CLI, and the second is in `\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.x.y\bin\`. You should check the second one